# SQL Server 2008 - Changing Identity increment of a primary key in a table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am changing the increment (making it 2 instead of 1) in identity of a column. SQL Server giving me the following error while making change to DB. I searched on internet but some of people saying that this can be a hardware issue but I've tried the same thing on different machine but it is giving me the same error. Following is the error...

> Unable to modify table.   SQL Server detected a logical
>   consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0x0c413292;
>   actual: 0x0c413282). It occurred during a read of page (1:21513) in
>   database ID 7 at offset 0x0000000a812000 in file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TimeCommerceV5.mdf'.  Additional
>   messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide
>   more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database
>   integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database
>   consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many
>   factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for response. I've already taken the backup of the DB. May be a good luck. And one more thing to notice is that I've tried this identity increment on the DB which I have got from my client. So, Can we say that DB is already corrupted. If yes, then what is the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a good backup? It might be time to use it. I doubt this has anything to do with changing the identity increment but rather is caused by trying to copy/write data to/from a bad page. What does `DBCC CHECKDB` yield? How about:

```
DBCC PAGE(7, 1, 21513, 3);
```

Comment: I've run the command you pasted and given this result "DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator."

Comment: Which command? DBCC PAGE or DBCC CHECKDB? See @Andrew's answer for a more complete command to run. You need to include the right database name for CHECKDB.

Comment: DBCC PAGE(7, 1, 21513, 3);

Comment: And you're still getting the same error if you try the identity change, that references database ID 7, file 1, page 21513? Or do you get a new page each time? You could try database name instead of 7 but that seems to indicate to me that the page it's complaining about doesn't exist - either because something has changed about the database (table has moved, database has been restored and now has a new ID, etc) or that the error is happening during the re-creation of the table and then is rolled back.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of the results, I would say that your C:\ is on its way out and you should think about replacing it or moving your databases to a different machine. A different drive won't help because that's where your O/S is and presumably where SQL Server is installed as well, so it's only a matter of time before the drive really croaks on you.

Comment: Error is the same. And about different machine, I have one instance of this data base on a different machine but error is the same on that machine also

Comment: So what happens with `DBCC CHECKDB(TimeCommerceV5) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS;`?

Comment: It has given me a list of errors. copying it to notepad file exceeded 1mb file size. I am now coordinating with the provider of this DB. Let's see what happens

Comment: Sorry, for the DBCC PAGE command you need to turn on `DBCC TRACEON (3604, -1);` - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved from comments)
Voted to move to serverfault, I would believe the error you are being given and your immediate move is to not panic, and backup the database immediately. Then you can start looking a dbcc checkdb and look at what has corrupted.

I can not stress enough that the **'do not panic'** and **'backup the database immediately'** have to be your next two steps.

Once that has been done, run

```
DBCC CHECKDB (YOURDBNAME) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS
```

And come back to us / serverfault with the output, if you are lucky it is just a non-clustered index that has corrupted.